# stack overflow dump in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I can see a lot of people are using stack data in elastic search (in tutorials). From where do I get JSON dump of stack overflow data that can be directly imported in elasticsearch?

Comment: you could use their [api](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a 24 GB anonymized data dump available from archive.org.

You can find it here:
https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Recommended is to download it using their torrent file:
https://archive.org/download/stackexchange/stackexchange_archive.torrent

You can also read the original and official blog post [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-cc-data-now-hosted-by-the-internet-archive/). And another interesting piece of info was the post on meta asking for [the schema of that data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) (it might be outdated though).

Then, you can check out [this project](https://github.com/o19s/StackExchangeElasticSearch) in order to index that data into your Elasticsearch.